# Python Selenium Passing Browser to Function

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a thread creating a selenium browser with PhantomJS

```
Browser= webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\phantomjs.exe',desired_capabilities=dcap, service_args=service_args)
```

But I want to continue to loop over data on this page unless conditions are met. The easiest way I can think to do this is to set a separate function but passing the browser to the function doesn't seem to work like this:

```
DoTheThing(Browser)
```

The DoTheThing function doesn't seem to have any access to that browser. Is there a way to do this or will I have to keep recreating the browser in each function. Or maybe somehow make it global which wouldn't be neat but it'd work for this case.

Comment: It is working fine on my machine. Could you show the full code, version of PhantomJS, and version of Python?

Comment: It depends of what `DoTheThing()` function is. `Browser` is a `webdriver` instance and you should know how to correctly operate with it